# PhoneGap GPS detect plugin not working

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

I am creating a Android mobile app using phonegap cli. It requires GPS to be enabled. I tried this plugin [gps detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-gpsdetect) from npm that will open Location settings if GPS is not enabled.It is not working even if I tried on of default template phonegap Hello World. Do you guys know any plugin or javascript code that detect if GPS is enabled or disable?

Comment: What do you mean by not working ! ! Show us what you have tried . Post some of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use checkGPS plugin for detect GPS is enabled or disabled.
https://github.com/fastrde/cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps